# Syntax for CHECKing inserted value against another table's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm adding a table in my Database:

```
***Enrollments***
CourseID
Student ID
EnrollmentDateTime
```

I already have a table:

```
***Courses***    
CourseID    
StartDate
```

When someone's inserted data into the Enrollments table, I want to check whether the enrollment date is lesser than/ before the start date; I know what needs to be done, but am lacking the syntax on how to do so. So far, I have the following, but am at a loss on how to proceed.

```
Create Table Enrollments(
    StudentID int NOT NULL Foreign Key REFERENCES dbo.Students(StudentID),
    CourseID int NOT NULL Foreign Key REFERENCES dbo.Courses(CourseID),
    EnrollmentDateTime Datetime NOT NULL CHECK (dbo.fCheckDate(EnrollmentDateTime, CourseID) = 1))
```

...

```
create function dbo.fCheckDate (@StartDate Datetime, @CourseID int)
Returns bit
AS 
Begin 
 Return(SELECT E.StartDate 
    FROM dbo.Enrollments E
    WHERE @CourseID = E.CourseID
End
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Such function-based checks are quite expensive.  But, you need a function to return the course date:

```
create function dbo.getStartDate (@CourseID int)
Returns datetime
AS 
Begin 
     Return (SELECT c.StartDate 
             FROM dbo.Courses c 
             WHERE c.CourseID = @CourseID 
            );
End;

Create Table Enrollments (
    StudentID int NOT NULL Foreign Key REFERENCES dbo.Students(StudentID),
    CourseID int NOT NULL Foreign Key REFERENCES dbo.Courses(CourseID),
    EnrollmentDateTime Datetime NOT NULL CHECK (EnrollmentDateTime < getStartDate(CourseID))
);
```